# How can I catch a Node app crash while using npm forever?

Tags: npm, forever

I am using *npm forever* to run a Node.js app. Forever will restart the app in case of a crash. I want to get notified that the Node app crashed and had to be restarted. How can I set this up? Is there any option apart from looking at the logs?

Comment: perhaps this could help https://github.com/sdolard/node-crashreporter

Comment: thanks  Krzysztof. yes, I can add the package to app.js, however I wonder if there is anything in forever to signal that crash happened?

Comment: besides logs there is no such functionality